# Google Sheets v4 API: unusual 503 when cloning sheet

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets-api

Am running Python 2.7 script that can successfully clone a sheet (index: 0) into the same spreadsheet, but fails when trying the second sheet (index: 1). The sheet has no special validation, formatting, or any unusual input - it's a grid with text.

Output from the script is:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/****/sheets/1:copyTo?alt=json returned "The service is currently unavailable.">
```

This happens on the API Explorer site as well. I've pulled the metadata from the sheet and can confirm all looks OK, and the index ID is correct. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

assumed using the index ID would be enough, but it specifically has to be the `sheetId`. User error. ('`1694990728`' instead of '`1`')

Comment: It says I can't do it for another 2 days.

Comment: Ah, true because you are a new member. Welcome :)

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using PHP to clone to Google sheet. It throws me the 500 error. I correctly specified the destination spreadsheet id, current Sheet id and index number.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo
Please help!